# Creating custom shapes in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create some common shapes in my flutter app like Circle, Star, Rectangle, Polygon etc.

The entire shape thing will depend on a ShapeEnum:

```
ShapeEnum {
  CIRCLE,
  STAR,
  RECTANGLE,
}
```

So that I can do this:

```
CustomShapedWidget(
  shape: ShapeEnum.STAR,
  child: Container....
)
```

I found out some Offset points for shapes like Star and Rectangle and here is what I did so far:

```
enum ShapeEnum {
  CIRCLE,
  STAR,
  SQUARE,
}

class CustomShapedWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final ShapeEnum shape;
  final Widget child;

  const CustomShapedWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.shape,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 15,
      height: 15,
      child: CustomPaint(
        size: Size(15, 15),
        painter: _CustomShapedPainter(
          shape: shape,
          size: Size(15, 15),
        ),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _CustomShapedPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final ShapeEnum shape;
  final Size size;

  _CustomShapedPainter({
    required this.shape,
    required this.size,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round; // Round the corners

    switch (shape) {
      case ShapeEnum.CIRCLE:
        final path = Path();
        final center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
        final radius = min(size.width, size.height) / 2;
        // path.arcTo(
        //     Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: radius), 0, 360, false);
        path.addPolygon(Shapes.circle, true);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        break;
      case ShapeEnum.SQUARE:
        final path = Path();
        path.addPolygon(Shapes.square, true);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        break;
      case ShapeEnum.STAR:
        final path = Path();
        path.addPolygon(Shapes.star, true);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

I am getting the shapes correct but cannot get the size right. Assume that I want a CustomSizedWidget of size 12.

I am getting the same size no matter what I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using enhanced enums solves the issue, you can easily define the size property on the enum and use it anywhere.

```
enum ShapeType {
  circle('circle', Size(12, 12)),
  square('square', Size(100, 100)),
  star('star', Size(50, 15)),
  ;

  const ShapeType(this.shape, this.size);

  final String shape;
  final Size size;
}
```

I created [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=7b92fe91cba753b75a42a67bd44c43d4) you can use and test this quickly, I couldn't get your offsets, so I use some sample ones.

Comment: Haven't worked with enhanced enums yet. But since the dartpad solution works, I'll try to integrate it with my code.